Not using R3DSDK -- disabled
Not using R3DSDK -- disabled
-- Nuke library not found
--     Try setting Nuke_ROOT ?
-- Found OpenGL
CMake Warning at src/cmake/checked_find_package.cmake:134 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but
CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with any of
the following names:
Qt6Config.cmake
qt6-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
src/cmake/externalpackages.cmake:199 (checked_find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:159 (include)
-- Qt6 library not found
--     Try setting Qt6_ROOT ?
-- Found Qt5 5.12.8
-- Downloading local Tessil/robin-map
-- Found Robinmap
-- Found fmt 10.2.2
-- All build dependencies: BZip2 1.0.8;DCMTK 3.6.4;FFmpeg 4.2;fmt 10.2.2;Freetype 2.10.1;GIF 5.1.9;Imath 3.2.0;JXL 0.10.2;Libheif 1.17.6;libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3;LibRaw 0.21.2;OpenColorIO 1.1.1;OpenCV 4.2.0;OpenEXR 3.3.0;OpenGL;OpenJPEG 2.3;OpenVDB 11.0.0;PNG 1.6.37;Ptex 2.4;pybind11 2.4.3;Python 3.11.9;Qt5 5.12.8;Qt6 NONE;Robinmap;TBB 2021.13.0;TIFF 4.1.0;WebP;ZLIB 1.2.11
-- OpenEXR core library will be used by default
-- OpenEXR core library will be used by default
-- Missing test data oiio-images
-- Missing test data openexr-images
-- Missing test data fits-images
-- Missing test data j2kp4files_v1_5

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
